# Tfidf transformer (sklearn) results in : "no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, text-analysis

I have a list of string that I fit_transform into CountVectorizer.

When I try to TfidfTransform it, I get the error:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit(features_train)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

Comment: @PhilipBergström No it doesn.t. It needs a count matrix. So what the OP indends to do is correct.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

You are not supplying the count matrix to the TfidfTransformer correctly.

`count_vect.fit(features_train)` will not return a count matrix. It returns `self`, means that it will return a fitted version of the CountVectorizer class.

For returning the count matrix, you need to call `transform()` method.

Correct the code like this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()

# This changed
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(features_train)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
```

Now you should not get any error.

By the way, instead of calling CountVectorizer and then TfidfTransformer separately, I would advise you to use [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) which is just a combination of these two, which reduces your code to:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(features_train)
```

Comment: I ended up doing the Tfidfvectorizer and is working now. Thanks!